# Remove ("erase") polygons by shared attribute

Tags: r, sf, parallel-processing, st-difference

I need to do a pair-wise removal of a set of polygons within a larger set of polygons.

```
pt<-data.frame("x"= c(0,0),"y"= c(0,5),pair= c("a","b"))
pt<- st_as_sf(pt, coords = c("x","y"), dim="XY", crs=  "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0")

big.c<-st_buffer(pt, dist=7)
big.c$size<-"x"
lil.c<- st_buffer(pt, dist=1)
lil.c$size<-"y"
circ<-as.data.frame(rbind(big.c,lil.c)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "size", values_from = "geometry")
```

Now I want to remove the inner circle (y[1]) from the corresponding big circle (x[1]) by row. If I just use st_difference it will remove any little circles that overlap with big circles, which I don't want. I want donuts.

Secondly, I will need to do this on a very large dataset. St_difference isn't particularly fast and I'm worried about running into a RAM issue. It would be great to create a lapply() so I can parallelize it. Unfortunately, my brain struggles with lapply() and I can't figure out how to enter 2 columns/lists in a lapply. Clearly this one doesn't work:

```
diff<- lapply(circ[,c("x","y")], function(x,y) {st_difference(x,y)})
```

because plot(diff[[1]]) plots the original circles.
I've considered doing it in ArcGIS Pro because I thought 'Pairwise Erase' would work quicker, but that gives the same result as st_difference, with multiple holes in each overlapping big circle, and I don't know how to customize it.

How do I get my donuts?

Answer (score 0):

How about applying a little filter based on `pair` to exclude the failed donuts and only retain the ones you want to keep?

```r
diff <- st_difference(big.c, lil.c) 

diff
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -7 ymin: -7 xmax: 7 ymax: 12
#> CRS:           +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
#>     pair size pair.1 size.1                       geometry
#> 1      a    x      a      y POLYGON ((6.990407 -0.36635...
#> 2      b    x      a      y POLYGON ((6.990407 4.633648...
#> 1.1    a    x      b      y POLYGON ((6.990407 -0.36635...
#> 2.1    b    x      b      y POLYGON ((6.990407 4.633648...

diff <- diff |> dplyr::filter(pair == pair.1)

diff
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -7 ymin: -7 xmax: 7 ymax: 12
#> CRS:           +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
#>     pair size pair.1 size.1                       geometry
#> 1      a    x      a      y POLYGON ((6.990407 -0.36635...
#> 2.1    b    x      b      y POLYGON ((6.990407 4.633648...

st_geometry(diff[1, ]) |> plot(border = "blue")
st_geometry(diff[2, ]) |> plot(border = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Are you actually running into issues or are you just worried about? I'd at least try this on your actual dataset.

Comment: Somehow I didn't realize that st_difference was creating a different polygon for every instance of smaller circle within a bigger circle. Yes, filter works! However, I did still have the issues of allocating enough RAM for st_difference. I worked around it by cutting my data into chunks and feeding it through a for loop. It took some time to run but it got the job done. Thank you @falk_env